# Are SRI's integrity and crossorigin values kept in package.json or elsewhere?

Tags: html, npm, subresource-integrity

This is bootstrap's official CDN stylsheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
```

However in my markup I don't hardcode the version because that can change, so I pull it out of my build system or app. A fictitious example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://foo.bar.com/jquery/$VERSION/all.min.js" />
```

As you can see `$VERSION` is not hardcoded. So I can change which version I'm using during the build process (in `package.json`) and not have to edit my app.

Now I want to add `integrity` in the same way. I was hoping I could find it in a `package.json`, but for bootsrap for example it's not there. I assume for other packages too.

I know I can [calculate it](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-subresource-integrity/#integrity-metadata-description) like this:

```
echo -n "alert('Hello, world.');" | openssl dgst -sha384 -binary | openssl base64 -A
```

but I don't want to overcomplicate my build system.

Is there some place I can get this value from, without having to hardcode it? I pull the version automatically from my project's `package.json` (or the one in `node_modules/bootstrap`) so I am hoping to do something similar for integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value isn't easily accessible from the `package.json` or elsewhere in a package's directory, I use the [ssri npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssri).

More work, but doesn't look like there's a better way.